# How to enable code completion in PyCharm for developing LibreOffice macros in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm, libreoffice

I am trying to use PyCharm to develop LibreOffice macros in Python. My code works, but PyCharm underlines big parts of the code in red, and code completion does not work for modules that begin with `com.sun.star.awt`. Here's how it looks:

[image: libreoffice macro development in pycharm]

Is it possible to make PyCharm aware of `com.sun.star.awt` modules? How?

Comment: Depends on how you created the project. Do you have a `setup.py`?

Comment: Menu: File / Invalidate Caches and Restart

Comment: @ThomasWeller Did not work. Everything is still underlined in red.

Comment: @smac89 I just have one python file, `messagebox.py`. Why do I need a `setup.py`? I am not developing a package, just a LibreOffice macro. And the macro works. The problem is that PyCharm does not "see" `com.sun.star.awt`.

Comment: Pycharm needs to know the structure of your project. Do you have the package that contains the module `com.sun.star.awt`, installed globally?

Comment: @smac89 Probably I don't have this package. I tried searching for it in LibreOffice folder but found nothing. Yet somehow my Python script works (when I run it from LibreOffice as a Python macro). That's basically my question - how to make PyCharm aware of this package.

Comment: `com.sun.star.awt` appears to be Java code, I don't think PyCharm will have much success doing auto-completion based on its content. LibreOffice *might* be able to run such python macros, but possibly because it may know what to do with the info PyCharm doesn't really understand.